# equivalent of rm –rf in c

Tags: c, linux, unix

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How to delete a directory and its contents in (POSIX) C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467725/how-to-delete-a-directory-and-its-contents-in-posix-c)

This is in a standard Linux environment.

Thanks!

(I'm aware of `rmdir` but this isn't what I'm looking for.)

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to [traverse the directory tree](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Working-with-Directory-Trees.html#Working-with-Directory-Trees), using [nftw](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/ftw.3.html) for file tree walk. For the `rm -r` example, use the flag `FTW_DEPTH` to process contents first, and check for `FTW_D` to use rmdir on directories rather than remove or unlink. Of course this doesn't guarantee you're allowed to remove things; that's generally decided by write persmission of the containing directory.

Comment: `ftw` was obsoleted by the much-better `nftw`.

Answer (score -1):

What's wrong with `system("rm -rf");`?

---

update: since commenters are showing with their comments that it's easy to miss the point, let me expand to clarify:

```
if (chdir(dirName) != 0)
  return -1;
if (system("rm -rf .") != 0)
  return -2;
```

Comment: The fact that it's using `system`, and you'll probably introduce **extremely serious** vulns when you go tacking on a name to the end of that...

Comment: Consider when someone gives you a name like `{/,foo}` or `* ~` (the classical mistake of a space while trying to remove only backup copies).

Comment: @R that's outside the scope of the question isn't it? besides, your point could apply to any other method as long as you don't check the inputs. just `chdir()`ing to the directory you want to remove, checking that you unded up somewhere sane and then `system("rm -rf .");` should be safe...

Comment: Not to mention arguments like `foo ; mailx -s 'I resign' my-boss` (standard command injection)

Comment: @TobySpeight read my comment immediately above yours.

Comment: I updated my answer to preempt further pointless comments.

Comment: You can't `rm -rf .`; it tries to remove the directory that it's being run from, which will always fail, and (in this example) will cause the calling function to return `-2`.

Comment: The update improves things; it may be wise to avoid depending on `PATH`, too (either unset the variable, or specify the absolute path to `rm`).