# What happens when unlink a directory?

Tags: linux, unlink, rmdir

Suppose `c.txt` is in directory `b`. `unlink c.txt` is easy, the system just removes entry `{XXX, c.txt}` in directory `b`. But what happens if `b` is a subdirectory of `a`, and I want to unlink `b`, is the procedure the same or more complicated?

Answer (score 5):

`unlink(2)` can only delete a file, while `rmdir(2)` can only delete empty directory.

If you want to delete directory recursively, you must use both syscalls intelligently. You may find many different implementations of recursive delete, for example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5467788/1734130) is using `nftw`, or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2256974/1734130) is using `opendir`/`readdir`.

Comment: suppose we have "a/b/c", and there is another "d/e" where e is a hard link of c, if we remove directory a and its subcontent, then where does e points to, invalid?

Comment: I refered to `Principles of Computer System Design`,in this condition, e ends up as a dangling reference which is not disruptive.

Comment: @stonestrong If it is a /symbolic/ link, it'll end up as a dangling reference, but a /hardlink/ will cause the file to still have a use count of 1, so there file is still there. You can try this yourself with: `mkdir -p a/b ;
echo Hello, World\! > a/b/c ;
mkdir d ;
ln -s ../a/b/c d/e ;
ln a/b/c d/f ;
rm -rf a ;
cat d/e ;
cat d/f`

Answer (score 1):

From man page for unlink:

```
When the utility is called as unlink, only one argument, 
which must not be a directory, may be supplied.
```

So when using unlink, you cannot pass directory as a parameter.

Comment: when talking about why Unix file system allows only links to files, not to directories, `Principles of Computer System Design` give an example of unlink a directory, it's on Page 100. If the example is not appropriate, is there any better explanation?

Answer (score 0):

On Linux it seems the result is EISDIR, however on OSX the result seems to be EPERM, so apparently you can't safely call unlink() on something and then try it as a directory only if unlink() fails.

```
dickbutt:~/unlink$ uname -a
Linux dickbutt 4.14.69-0-vanilla #1-Alpine SMP Mon Sep 10 19:33:23 UTC 2018 x86_64 Linux
dickbutt:~/unlink$ cat ./unlink.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    int ret = unlink("./xxx");
    printf("ret is [%d] and errno is [%d] aka [%s]\n", ret, errno,
strerror(errno));
}
dickbutt:~/unlink$ mkdir xxx
dickbutt:~/unlink$ gcc ./unlink.c
dickbutt:~/unlink$ ./a.out
ret is [-1] and errno is [21] aka [Is a directory]
dickbutt:~/unlink$
```

```
notgay:unlink user$ uname -a
Darwin notgay.local 14.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 14.5.0: Sun Jun  4 21:40:08 PDT 2017; root:xnu-2782.70.3~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
notgay:unlink user$ cat ./unlink.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    int ret = unlink("./xxx");
    printf("ret is [%d] and errno is [%d] aka [%s]\n", ret, errno, strerror(errno));
}
notgay:unlink user$ mkdir xxx
notgay:unlink user$ gcc ./unlink.c
notgay:unlink user$ ./a.out
ret is [-1] and errno is [1] aka [Operation not permitted]
notgay:unlink user$
```