# Command line app: Unix cd command

Tags: unix, command-line

My Mac OS command line application is making Unix calls such as:

```
system("rm -rf /Users/stu/Developer/file);
```

perfectly successfully.

So why is the following not changing the current directory?

```
system("cd /Users/me/whatever");
system("pwd");    //cd has not changed
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because

> `system()` executes a command specified in *command* by calling **`/bin/sh -c`** *`command`*, and returns after the command has been completed.

So each command is executed independently, each in a new instance of the shell.

So your first call spawns a new `sh` (with your current working directory), changes directories, and then exits.  Then the second call spawns a new `sh` (again in your CWD).

See the [man page for `system()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system).

---

The better solution is [**to not use `system`**](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/ENV04-C.+Do+not+call+system%28%29+if+you+do+not+need+a+command+processor). It has some inherent flaws that can leave you open to security vulnerabilities.  Instead of executing `system()` commands, you should use the equivalent POSIX C functions.  *Everything*  that you can do from the command-line, you can do with C functions (how do you think those utilities work?)

- Instead of `system("rm -rf ...")` use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467725/how-to-delete-a-directory-and-its-contents-in-posix-c).
- Instead of `system("cd ...")` use [`chdir()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/chdir).
- Instead of `system("pwd ...")` use [`getcwd()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getcwd).

There are some differences, of course, but these are the fundamental equivalents of what you're trying to do.